# Windows phone 8.1 save data with javascript

Tags: javascript, windows

is there any way to save settings data with javascript in windows phone 8.1 application. In C# is ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings. Is anything like that
possible in javascript?

Thank you

Comment: [_localStorage_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage)?

Answer (score 1):

The same API is available to HTML/Javascript apps. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465118.aspx) for more information.

```
var localSettings = applicationData.localSettings;
var localFolder = applicationData.localFolder;
localSettings.values["exampleSetting"] = "Hello Windows";
```